# WPF: Slider with dragging event (pause while dragging, without releasing the thumb)

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

Functionality: Drag the thumb and if user pauses for a certain time without releasing the thumb I want to do something. How can I achieve this?

I understand the OnThumbDragDelta, OnThumbDragCompleted, OnThumbDragStarted methods, but all of them fires when the value changes. I need to fire an event when slider stays at a value for a certain time while the thumb is being dragged.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by combining your desired `Event` with a `Timer` (which works as a countdown).
In your case you might use `Slider.OnValueChanged` instead of `OnThumbDragDelta`, `OnThumbDragCompleted` and so on.

Everytime that `Event` is raised reset that timer. And when the countdown elapsed do whatever you want.

---

```
private DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
```

Initialization (e.g. in your constructor):

```
dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1); //Or whatever time you like
dispatcherTimer.Tick += DispatcherTimer_Tick;
```

```
private void OnEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}
```

```
private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    //Your code
}
```